# What is the runtime complexity of Vec::len?

Tags: rust

Given a vector...

```
let v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Is calling `v.len()` O(1) or O(n)?

---

Neither "The Book" (from what I can tell so far) nor [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#len.v) mention whether `.len()` is constant time or not, and I cannot find anything on Stack Overflow or elsewhere.

I'm assuming it's O(1) since `[]`, `.push()`, and `.pop()` [all are](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/), but I want to be sure before I litter my code with `v.len()`.

I know that I can easily just store/reference the return of `len` but in some situations - like inner functions - I don't want to keep having to pass both a vector *and* an int around.

Thanks to @Stargateur for pointing out that indexing's O(1) is different from push/pop's *amortized* O(1)

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec.rs.html#1163-1165

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Ugh, embarrassing... I had a hard time finding that one... Can you post that as an answer please?

Comment: @kevlarr: Nothing embarrassing here; except for the Docs of course. It would indeed be nice that the complexity of each collection method was made explicit in its doc. I mean, the implementation of `len` is easy here, but what's the complexity of `drain_filter`?

Comment: @MatthieuM. good point!

Comment: `push()` is not `O(1)` but amortized `O(1)`, sometime the resize need `O(n)`

Comment: @Stargateur Oh good call, I missed that distinction

Comment: Thank you @Shepmaster for the good edits to question & answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is `O(1)` as of [the implemented code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.25.0/src/liballoc/vec.rs#L1163-L1165) in Rust 1.25.0:

```
pub fn len(&self) -> usize {
    self.len
}
```